# Calculate CRC64 to match Azure value given in report

Tags: c#, azure

I am using the Azure Databox. I copy files on to the databox. Ship the databox to MS. MS loads the databox to Azure blob storage and provides me with the CRC64 value in a report.

After I download the file I need to calculate the CRC of the file to validate the the file was downloaded correctly.

example CRC:

```
<file size="345371864" crc64="0x23ac857f79a45e3d">\46fdbfac-f44a-4517-eeca-fca347e33bd0\13357.dat</file>
```

Anybody know what CRC64 algorithm MS uses? Any MS c# libraries available?

Thoughts?

Gina

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fciads/2cfdd8d0-8730-4340-b04e-8d588669fb35

Comment: https://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/19/calculating-crc-64-in-c-and-net

Comment: @MitchWheat So the second link you provided is for CRC ISO-3309. I will try that and get back

Comment: @MitchWheat Values don't match. I will see if I can get in touch with damieng. I've tried 9 different algorithms so far.

Comment: @Gina Marano have you found an implementation of MS's CRC64 algorithm? Having exactly the same issue.